# Why ITextSharp takes long time to create pdf?

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, itext

my application first load the text file in richtextbox whitout any problem :

```
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt");

        while (str.Peek() != -1)
        {

            richtextbox1.AppendText(str.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

after that , i want to export the text of richtextbox to pdf format using itextsharp :

```
      iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filename,        FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richtextbox1.Text));
        doc.Close();
```

i have used backgroundworker but it did not help me :

```
     private delegate void upme(string filenamed);

   private void callpdf(string filename)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richtextbox1.Text));
        doc.Close();
    }

    private void savepdfformat(string filenames)
 {
     BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();

     bg.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
     {
        upme movv = new upme(callpdf);

        richtextbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(movv, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, filenames);

     };
     bg.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("done");
     };

     bg.RunWorkerAsync();   
}
```

the test.txt is about 2 mb size , it loads very fast in richtextbox1 but when i want to

convert it to pdf, it takes very time and the application hangs.

what should i do for optimization?

thanks for any help.

Comment: A few quick comments: (1) can you provide some contents for the rtf file (2) if your application is hanging its because you are processing on the main thread. Process on a background/worker thread and your application will continue to run normally. (3) how long is a "very long time"?

Comment: i have used background worker but it did not help. it takes very long time. now i will update the code using background worker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple: read the text.txt file line by line, create a `Paragraph` for each line and add each `Paragraph` object to the document as soon as possible.

Why is this the solution?

Your code is flawed by design: it consumes an enormous amount of memory: first you load 2 MByte in the `richtextbox1` object. Then you load the same 2 MByte into the `Paragraph` object. The original 2 MByte is still in memory, but `Paragraph` starts allocating memory to process the text. Then you add the `Paragraph` to the document. Memory is released on a page per page basis (iText flushes content as soon as a page is full), but the processing still requires plenty of memory. When your computer "hangs", he's probably swapping memory.

I see that your nickname is Smart Man, but I guess you're a Young Man. If you were as old as I am, you'd have known the days when memory was expensive and one couldn't afford wasting memory by design ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer , i wil keep it in my mind. +1 vote up for you.